# How can I parameterize Athena Queries using boto3 version 1.17 in python?

Tags: sql, python-2.7, boto3, amazon-athena

I am not able to pass execution parameters to Athena using boto3 version 1.17. I know for boto3 version 1.24 and above you can use the parameter "ExecutionParameters" in the input (Refer https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/athena.html#Athena.Client.start_query_execution) but boto3 1.17 does not support it.
So for example I have this query "SELECT * FROM table WHERE x i (?) AND y in (?)" how can I replace the values in the placeholders. Is there a way without using prepared statements?

P.S: I have to use boto3 1.17 version only.

Comment: You can use string interpolation if you trust the input.

Comment: Can you use f-string in python?